# Do the independent vectors of some set of vectors span the same subspace as the basis of the subspace constructed by them?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

To be more specific
Do the basis constructed by finding ref of a matrix consisting of some vectors put in rows span the same subspace as the independent vectors situated in the pivot columns of the matrix constructed by the same vectors put in columns?

Comment: Are you asking whether the columns of the reduced echelon form of a matrix span the same subspace as the columns of the original matrix? This is something you can fairly easily play with in an example to get an idea...

Comment: What I am asking is are the pivot columns of the row echelon form of a matrix constructed by putting vectors vertically (by columns) span the same subspace as the non zero rows of the row echelon form of the matrix constructed by the same vector, which in this case are put horizontically (by rows)

Comment: @Ian the question (if I understood it correctly) is as follows: there are two standard methods to produce a basis given a list of vectors.  The first method is to build a matrix using the vectors as columns, row reduce, then select the columns (from the original matrix, i.e. the original set) corresponding to the pivot columns to form a basis.  The second method is to build the matrix using the vectors as rows, row reduce, then use the non-zero rows to form a basis.  The question is whether these methods produce a basis for the same space.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thank you, that is exactly what I am asking

Comment: @Karen so in short, the answer is yes: both methods produce a basis for the span of the original set of vectors, so both bases have the same span.

Answer (score 2):

Both of these methods are designed to produce a basis for the span of the set that we started with.  Since these are two bases of the same subspace of $\Bbb R^n$, they certainly have the same span.

Any rigorous proof of this would amount to proving that each method does what it is supposed to do, which I suspect would not be very enlightening.  So, instead of going through a proof, let's consider an example.  Consider the set $S = \{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\} \subset \Bbb R^4$, where we are given the column-vectors
$$
v_1 = (1,2,3,4), \quad v_2 = (2,4,6,8),
\quad v_3 = (2,3,4,5),\quad v_4 = (3,4,5,6).
$$
With each method, our goal is to produce a basis for the span of $S$, i.e. the set of all vectors $a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + a_3 v_3 + a_4 v_4$. Using the column-method, we end up with the row reduction
$$
\pmatrix{v_1&v_2&v_3&v_4} = \pmatrix{1 & 2 & 2 & 3\\ 2 & 4 & 3 & 4\\ 3 & 6 & 4 & 5\\ 4 & 8 & 5 & 6}
\leadsto 
\pmatrix{
1 & 2 & 0 & -1\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 2\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
}.
$$
So, the set $\{v_1,v_3\}$ should give us a basis. Looking at the non-pivot columns of the row-reduced matrix gives us an idea as to why this works. In the row-reduced matrix, we see that the second column is $2$ times the first, and the last column is $-1$ of the first column and $2$ of the third. Since the columns of the row-reduced matrix have the same "relations" as the columns of the original matrix, we have
$$
v_2 = 2v_1, \quad v_4 = -v_1 + 2v_3.
$$
With that, we can see that for any $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$, we have
$$
a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + a_3 v_3 + a_4 v_4 = \\
a_1 v_1 + a_2 (2v_1) + a_3 v_3 + a_4 (-v_1 + 2v_3) = \\
a_1 v_1 + 2a_2 v_1 + a_3 v_3 -a_4 v_1 + 2a_4 v_3 = \\
(a_1 + 2a_2 - a_4)v_1 + (a_3 + 2a_4)v_3.
$$
So indeed, every element of the span is a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_3$.

Using the row-method, we end up with the row-reduction
$$
\pmatrix{v_1^T\\v_2^T\\v_3^T\\v_4^T} = 
\pmatrix{
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\ 2 & 4 & 6 & 8\\ 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 3 & 4 & 5 & 6
} \leadsto
\pmatrix{
1 & 0 & -1 & -2\\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
}.
$$
So, the set $\{w_1,w_2\}$ where $w_1 = (1, 0 , -1 , -2)$ and $w_2 = (0 , 1 , 2 , 3)$ should give a basis. In order to write the coordinates of each $v_i$ with respect to this basis, it suffices to look at the first two entries.  For instance, $v_3$ has $2,3$ as its first two entries, which means that we must have $v_3 = 2w_1 + 3w_2$.  We can therefore see that for every $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,$ we have
$$
a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + a_3 v_3 + a_4 v_4 = \\
a_1 (w_1 + 2w_2) + a_2 (2w_1 + 4w_2) + a_3 (2w_1 + 3w_2) + a_4 (3w_1 + 4w_2) = \\
(a_1 + 2a_2 + 2a_3 + 3a_4)w_1 + (2a_1 + 4a_2 + 3a_3 + 4a_4)w_2.
$$
So indeed, every element of the span is a linear combination of $w_1$ and $w_2$.